# Append data from another model in a model (laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to append the count of data from a table in my database but I am having a problem with the relationship.

I have 3 Models

**Voucher model**:

[vouchers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T94sF.png)

**VoucherSerial Model:**

[voucher_serials table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HOCD.png)

Each voucher will have many serials

**UserVoucher Model:**

[user_vouchers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbAEm.png)

When the user redeemed the voucher it will be stored in user_vouchers table. I also had defined the relationship for all the Models

In Voucher.php I want to append the count of the voucher redeemed by the user.

```
 public function  getVoucherRedeemedAttribute()
{         
   //query to append the voucher redeemed count for each voucher
}
```

I've tried so many solution but mostly I got errors. My biggest problem is because to count the voucher redeemed for each voucher based on user_vouches table but each voucher has many serial_id which i want to count as the same voucher

I know my explanation regarding the question is bad but I need some help regarding this. Hope someone can help me.

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: in place of eloquent you can use query builder method  . more about query https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries . if you it's okay with you ?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Gaurav. I'll try to familiar myself with your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the number of related objects to the result with the `withCount` method:

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without
>   actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will
>   place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models. For example:
>
> ```
> $posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();
>
> foreach ($posts as $post) {
>     echo $post->comments_count;
> }
> ```
>
> Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to get the count one level deeper (number of vouchers instead of number of voucher serials). You might be able to use a `hasManyThrough` relationship:

> The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For example, a Country model might have many Post models through an intermediate User model. In this example, you could easily gather all blog posts for a given country.
>
> Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Combined it will look something like this:

```
class User {
    //...
    public function vouchers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(App\Voucher::class, App\VoucherSerial::class);
    }
}

// Controller
$user->withCount('vouchers');
```

I've never actually used `withCount` and `hasManyThrough` together but it should work ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for you help @Thomas. It works perfectly :)

Comment: You're welcome. And please don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).